# Best way to iterate through multiple linked XML documents

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a large set of XML documents, let's say 3,000 files. Within these files are a structure to build an interactive document where each page has links to other pages.  My problem is that I need to find the right order of items based on a link tag and an attribute contained inside of it.  An issue I am running into is that I need these to be pulled out in the proper order and each XML document could have multiple links within it, with each of those links leading to a document with more links.

These documents would need to go in the following order.

DocA.XML has 4 links, DocB.XML, DocC.XML, DocD.XML and DocE.XML

If there were no further links in those 4 documents then this would be easy, I would just pull all the nodes out of DocA and do a For Each and pop the names of the 4 documents into my table. Problem is these documents have more links in them.

Let's say that...
DocB has 3 links (DocF, DocG, DocH)
DocC has 2 links (DocI, DocJ)
DocD has no links
DocE has 1 link (DocK)

Now...
DocF has 2 links (DocL, DocM)
DocJ has 3 links (DocL, DocN, DocO)
DocK has 2 links (DocL, DocO)

The rest have no links.  I threw some duplicates in there as that is a common issue and they don't always need to be shown, but I will get to that later.

So the way I need to pull the structure of these documents would be as follows.

DocA
- DocB
-- DocF
--- DocL
--- DocM
-- DocG
-- DocH
- DocC
-- DocI
-- DocJ
--- DocN (DocL is skipped because it already exists)
--- DocO
- DocD
- DocE (The end because DocL and DocO already exist)

I need to find a way in VB.NET to loop through these documents and search out any links within them to determine the proper order as indicated above.  These links could go as far as 12+ files where it just keeps linking out to another document.

Currently I have a terrible method that does this...

```
Dim xInstall As XmlNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//install/link")

For Each xInstallNode As XmlNode In xInstall
    Dim xAttr As XmlAttribute = CType(xInstallNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("xlink:href"), XmlAttribute)

    If xAttr IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim strLink As String = xInstallNode.Attributes("xlink:href").InnerText
        Dim strTaskDesc As String = xInstallNode.SelectSingleNode("prompt").InnerText

        Add_Subtask(intCount, strTaskDesc, strLink, 0, "Install")

        For m As Integer = 1 To 25
            For n As Integer = 0 To intCount
                Process_Next_Install(n)
            Next
        Next
    End If
Next xInstallNode
```

- Add_Subtask simply adds the information into a table an increments intCount.
- Process_Next_Install is where it goes through each item in the table and does the same thing as the above method but with some extra steps to ignore duplicates and such.
- intCount is the ID of the item being added.
- The 0 in the Add_Subtask is the parent's ID, so the first one would be 0, when I call the Add_Subtask in the Process_Next_Install method I call it with 'n' as the parent.

I have tried doing a For Each item in the table, but because the table is constantly being added to .NET doesn't appreciate that and tells me I can't iterate through a dynamic table.  Makes sense, it could go on forever as far as it knows.

Finally, **my question is** what is the best method to iterate through these documents understanding that I do not know where the end is and that I need them in a particular order?

I am having a difficult time trying to figure out what my Do Until should be because duplicates make it difficult to know when you are "at the end".

Apologies for the lengthy question.  Hopefully I have been able to provide enough information for someone to understand what it is I am looking for.  Been bashing my head against the wall on this for a while.  The code I have works, it gets everything I need but it's slow as hell and having a hard coded '25' or whatever number is not the right way to do this.  I know there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `recursion`.  The following pseudo code should start you off.

```
Sub My_Install(xInstall as ...)
    For each xInstallNode in xInstall
        Add_SubTask(...)
        For each (<xInstallLinked = linked file returned as XMLNodeList>)
            My_Install(xInstallLinked)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Obviously I have missed a lot of detail out, and you should also check for loops (could take a very long time to run otherwise!). In your example code above, the loop `for m = 1 to 25` does not achieve anything except run the same code 25 times - or is this just a case of selective editing to make a short example for this forum?

Comment: Running the same code 25 times is more or less just an arbitrary number that says run through the code 25 times, the first time it runs it's going to find the first link, the second time it will either find any links within the first link or if it doesn't it will find the next link in the first link, if that makes sense.  It's terrible and I know it, which is why I am looking for something else.

Comment: I will try out the recursion method to see if it works for my particular scenario, there are some annoyances in the rules that I need to follow that could cause issues such as the duplication I mentioned where sometimes it's ok to be a duplicate and sometimes it isn't.  Welcome to working with people who don't know how to write a requirements document I suppose.

Comment: Ok I've kind of got your pseudo code fleshed out.  The only thing that I'm not quite visualizing is the following line "For each (<xInstallLinked = linked file returned as XMLNodeList>)".  I have xInstallNode as an XMLNode (a link from the current document) but how do I return that as an XMLNodeList?

Comment: Actually, I just took out that second for each and just called the method again and it appears to be pulling out all the data in the correct order.  Small sample size, but I think this is what I needed!  I was close, but I had two methods instead of one which was definitely my problem.  Thanks for the help on this AJD I certainly appreciate the push in the right direction.